# AUCTeX: insert reference / citation without macro

Tags: emacs, auctex

Is there a way to add a reference / citation format which inserts the reference / citation label directly into the buffer without enclosing it into a macro?

To be clear: When I hit `C-c )` `AUCTeX` prompts for a reference format, when I hit `return` it'll insert `~\ref{LABEL}` into the buffer [after selecting the appropriate reference in the next buffer]. I would like to add a reference format which is bound to `\?s` (space) that inserts only the `LABEL` part.

That is to say: I hit `C-c )`, then `<space>`, then select the reference and... tadaa there's `LABEL` in the buffer.

**[Edit:]** I have tried

```lisp
(eval-after-load "latex"
       '(progn
          (add-to-list
                'reftex-ref-style-alist
                '("Default" t
                  (("" ?\s))))))
```

however this encloses the label in curly braces and prepends `~` if there's a word before point.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a solution by adding an `around-advice` to `reftex-reference`, however, it's not a pretty solution. I'll put it up as an answer but I'm still hoping for a better solution.

```lisp
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(progn
     (add-to-list
      'reftex-ref-style-alist
      '("Default" t
    (("LABEL ONLY" ?\s))))

     (defadvice reftex-format-special (around reftex-format-special-labely-only activate)
       "Advice `reftex-format-special' such that if
REFSTYLE is \"LABEL ONLY\" it will insert
only the reference's label."
       (if (string= (ad-get-arg 2) "LABEL ONLY")
       (setq ad-return-value (format "%s" (ad-get-arg 0)))
     ad-do-it))))
```